Circular progressbar as trailing icon
I have a OutlinedTextField with a trailing icon which changes according to a state.
Let's say, idling state in the beginning and then when trailing icon is pressed goes to loading and when the task is , state success, icon is a cross/cancel which cleans the text field.
What I want is to have a progressbar like an icon when the state is loading.
I currently use a CircularProgressbar composable but it does not look/feel like an icon.
Question
Is there a way to make the CircularProgressbar look like an icon in a generic way which works for any phones and sizes?
Or is there an easier way to do it?
Animating some icon could also be interesting.
Here is what I have done:
trailingIcon = {
                when(status) {
                    Status.IDLING -> IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.filterData(iNeedInput)
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Search, contentDescription = "search")
                    }
                    Status.SUCCESS -> IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            viewModel.updateSearchUi("")
                        }
                    ) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Clear, contentDescription = "clear")
                    }
                    Status.LOADING ->
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = {
                                viewModel.updateSearchUi("")
                            }
                        ) {
                            CircularProgressIndicator()
                        }
                    Status.FAILED ->  Icon(imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Info, contentDescription = "error")
                }
            }


One thing I do not understand is that why have you wrapped the CircularProgressIndicator() inside an IconButton? You could have just used CircularProgressIndicator().

The reason was to make sure that the paddings and sizes are not affected by the IconButton composable. I removed it and it still looks the same.

Icon uses LocalContentColor to draw, so you can use it too to set the color of the CircularProgressIndicator. Trailing icon size is 24dp by specs, you can also add padding(2.dp) to make it match the size of the other icons.
CircularProgressIndicator(
    color = LocalContentColor.current,
    strokeWidth = 2.dp,
    modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
)

Default:

Error:

Disabled:

Dark:


I am not sure if this can be done or not. since I am a beginner in compose but if we have a constrained layout then 24.dp would be a hard value!! Would all icons still look the same?

It won't affect other icons because only one of the composables selected by when(status) can exist at any given moment. In the worst case, if its size is too big, it can affect TextField size. @msc87
